# Unable to find campaigns in AD_PERFORMANCE_REPORT which are present in CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT

Tags: google-ads-api

Using the AdWords API, I'm not able to find all the campaigns present in the Adwords UI. These are present in the Campaign Performance Report but not in the Ad Performance Report. 
There is a difference of about 30 odd campaigns which I'm unable to account for.

I'm using the report_downloader from the google ads Python API with the following report definition:

```
 report_format = {
 'selector': {
 'fields': ['CampaignName'],
 },
 'reportName': '{:s}'.format(report),
 'reportType': '{:s}'.format(report),
 'downloadFormat': 'CSV',
 'dateRangeType': 'LAST_7_DAYS'
 }
```

The `report` is the variable that holds the report names : CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT and AD_PERFORMANCE_REPORT.
Could anyone shed some light on why this would happen ?

Thanks!

Comment: mmm, have they adgroups? are the adgroups active? have you experiments?

Comment: the missing ones are primarily app based campaigns.